# C# Finding element in List of String Arrays

Tags: c#

I cannot solve a problem for several hours now. 
Here is a simplified scenario. 
Let's say there is a list of people with their bids. I'm trying to find a person with the highest bid and return the name. I am able to find the highest bid, but how to I output the name?

```
        List<String[]> list = new List<String[]>();
        String[] Bob = { "Alice", "19.15" };
        String[] Alice = {"Bob", "28.20"};
        String[] Michael = { "Michael", "25.12" };

        list.Add(Bob);
        list.Add(Alice);
        list.Add(Michael);

        String result = list.Max(s => Double.Parse(s.ElementAt(1))).ToString();

        System.Console.WriteLine(result);
```

As a result I get 28.20, which is correct, but I need to display "Bob" instead. There were so many combinations with list.Select(), but no success. Anyone please?

Comment: Instead of using a Dictionary, it might be wiser to use a class for this. Check out Michel Keijzers' answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should work:

```
var max = list.Max(t => double.Parse(t[1]));
list.First(s => double.Parse(s[1]) == max)[0]; // If list is not empty
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the answer I was looking for! Maybe not as elegant, as defining a class, but I really tried to avoid it. Cheers!

Answer (score 9):

The best solution from an architectural point of view is to create a separate class (e.g. Person) that contains two properties Name and Bid of each person and a class Persons that contains the list of persons.

Then you can easily use a LINQ command.

Also instead of storing bids as string, think if bids as floating point or decimal values would be better (or store it in cents and use an int).

I don't have a compiler by hand so it's a bit out of my head:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float  Bid  { get; set; }

    public Person(string name, float bid)
    {
        Debug.AssertTrue(bid > 0.0);
        Name = name;
        Bid = bid;
    }
}

public class Persons : List<Person>
{
    public void Fill()
    {
        Add(new Person("Bob", 19.15));
        Add(new Person("Alice" , 28.20));
        Add(new Person("Michael", 25.12));
    }
}
```

In your class:

```
var persons = new Persons();
persons.Fill();

var nameOfHighestBidder = persons.MaxBy(item => item.Bid).Name;
Console.WriteLine(nameOfHighestBidder);
```

Comment: I do agree, the class would be easier to deal with. But due to the nature of the problem (web services, etc) I didn't want to create additional class. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Doesn't the Max method you used there return an int?

Comment: No problem at all ... I extended the answer anyway to show others how classes can help increase readability and splitting responsibilities.

Comment: I changed Max to MaxBy, assuming it returns the person with the maximum bid, and than take the name of that person.

Comment: Is it [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ)? I don't recall a `MaxBy` in .NET Framework.

Comment: @ŞafakGür Yes ... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188693/how-can-i-get-linq-to-return-the-object-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-given-prop/3188751

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Jon Skeet's MaxBy.](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs)

For usage you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920344/faster-way-to-count-number-of-sets-an-item-appears-in)
e.g. in this case

```
list.MaxBy(s => Double.Parse(s.ElementAt(1)))[0]
```

More [here](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)

Answer (score 5):

This works in the simple example. Not sure about the real one

```
var result = list.OrderByDescending(s => Double.Parse(s.ElementAt(1))).First();
```

Answer (score 2):

After finding result just do as below:

```
list.First(x=>x[1] == result)[0]
```